# javascript and iframe trouble

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm working with js and html, all client side. I have the following situation... I have an html form (in index.html) that contains some inputs and a submit button. Apart from that, the form contains an iframe tag which refers to another page (other.html) containing other html form. The thing is in this other page called other.html I have a text input (name="info") inside a form tag that saves some info.

Now what I want to do is submit this info's input value with the form of index.html.

Example index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="aphpfile.php">
            <input type="text" name="a"/>
            <input type="text" name="b"/>
            <input type="text" name="c"/>
            <iframe id="other1" width="408" height="200" frameborder="0" 
                scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
                marginwidth="0" src="other.html"></iframe>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example other.html:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setInfo() {
            document.getElementById("info").value = "this is the info";
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="info" name="info"/>
        </form>
        <input type="button" onclick="setInfo();" value="setInfo"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

So from aphpfile.php I want to do this:

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$info = $_POST['info'];
echo $a . "," . $b . "," . $c . "," . $info;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: append the variable as a hidden input to the form you are submitting via an ajax call. on the success function of the ajax call append the variable to your current form.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, could you give me an example please? I'm just learning js ajax and all this stuff. Thank you!

Comment: I got what you are saying, but i dont know how to write this ajax code you are talking about! thx again

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED for many iframes. The following code is written inside a function that is called when the form to aphpfile.php is submitted. I hope someone finds this useful :)

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('other1');
        var innerDoc;
        var data;
        var name;
        var htmlData="";
        var i=1;
        while(iframe != null)
        {
            innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
            data=innerDoc.getElementById("info").value;
            name="info"+i;
            htmlData+="<input type='hidden' name='"+name+"' value='"+data+"'/>";
            i++;
            iframe = document.getElementById('other'+i);
        }
        document.getElementById("hiddens").innerHTML=htmlData;
```

And ofc there is a

```
<div id="hiddens"></div>
```

inside the form in index.html